# How to make gdb show locals buffer in a different window?

Tags: buffers, gdb, gud

Using gdb in emacs, gdb shows the source code to the right of the gdb prompt.

According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-GDB-Buffers.html), I can do `M-x gdb-display-locals-buffer` which displays the local variables.
However, when I do that, the locals buffer replaces the source buffer. Is there a way for to tell gdb to open the locals buffer somewhere else? So that it doesn't overwrite the source buffer?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Bonus question, what is the difference between gdb and gud-gdb? Can I get the locals buffer using gud?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize your default GDB window layout, you
can do the following :

1. Enter GDB mode manually, and craft your layout using the
   regular `window-*` commands and the `gdb-display-*` commands.
2. Invoke `gdb-save-window-configuration` to save it to a file.
3. Set it as your default layout :

```lisp
(setq gdb-many-windows t)
(setq gdb-default-window-configuration-file "/path/to/file")
```

If you want to keep the default layout and be able to quickly
pull up the GDB locals buffer, you can write your own command
like so :

```lisp
(defun gdb-add-locals-buffer ()
  "Display the GDB locals buffer."
  (interactive)
  (split-window-below)
  (gdb-display-locals-buffer))
```

I tested this with the interactive GDB buffer on the left-hand
side, and the source buffer on the right-hand side. It worked, but
it is not reliable. You can also use `gdb-load-window-configuration`
to manually load a premade configuration.